generating pure errors (destabilizers) by given stabilizer and logical group
Suppose we have a stabilizer code on n physical qubits, with stabilizer group S and assume fixed representatives of the logical operators L. Given this fixed set of generators for S and L, can we define a unique (up to certain stabilizer transformations) set of pure error generators (or destabilizers) which generate the group of pure errors in stim?
The commutation relations say that the pure error generator T_{i} anticommutes
only with the stabilizer generator S_{i} and commutes with all other generators of S, L,
and T.
Given S, L is there a possibility to get T from stim library?

You want stim.Tableau.from_stabilizers. The z_outputs of the tableau are the stabilizers; the x_outputs are the corresponding destabilizers.

Ah, Ok. Can it also provide logical operators consistent with stabilizers/destabilizers?

@reza Yes, it will also solve for the observables.

@CraigGidney how will this work if the stabilizers are not independent?...e.g. if you give it all stabilizers of the toric code what would it return?

@unknown First, it will force you to specify allow_redundant=True to warn you what's happening. Then it will simply go stabilizer by stabiilizer, in order, dropping any that are redundant given the presence of the previous ones in the order. Then it solves as normal.

@CraigGidney, this is reasonable, but it does make the destabilizers dependent on the order the stabilizers are processed. I don't know if there's a "better" way that gives back a dependent set of destabilizers without favoring an order. For the toric code for example, the $L^2$  X (and $L^2$ Z) stabilizers are indistinguishable : you can drop any one of them to get an independent set ; you would think there's a way to get dependent destabilizers that are also indistinguishable.

@unknown The definition of a destabilizer is that it flips exactly one of the stabilizer generators. If you have linearly dependent generators, that becomes impossible to satisfy.

@CraigGidney, that's one way to define them...but it does favor a subset of the stabilizers. A more symmetric treatment would be that if you have $m$ stabilizers such that any $r$ of them are independent then you can find $m$ destabilizers that can be paired with the stabilizers so that an independent subset of stabilizers has a corresponding independent subset of destabilizers.

Ok, thanks that works. Is there a way to obtain LTS decompostion for given Pauli operator e? like how to get logical, pure and stabilizer part of a pauli operator assuming L, T, S has been given.

And, is there a way to partially fill up Tableau (like fill up all stabilizers and some of its destabilizer) and stim find the rest. I think I would like to fix some of destabilizer forms.

@reza No, I haven't implemented LTS in stim. And no I haven't implemented a version that lets you specify partial stabilizers and destabilizers, as I think there are multiple possible things that could mean.

Ah, ok, thanks for the info.
